# React JS- not able to detect 'show' function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, counter

I am trying to build a simple click counter in which the counter will increase by 1(initially 0) with each click. But the error I am getting is **'show' is defined but never used**.The function 'show' re-renders the DOM after each click as given in index.js file.

App.js file-

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>This div has been clicked {this.props.clicks} times.</div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

index.js file-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

let model = { clicks: 0 };

function show() {
  ReactDOM.render(<App clicks={model.clicks} onClick={()=> { model.clicks += 1; show();}} />, document.getElementById('root'));
}

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: use state not simple variable

Comment: That isn't how you do this with React, [more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). But ignoring that, whatever tool is telling you `show` is never used is simply incorrect. It *is* used. (But a click won't re-render anything. Again, that's not how you do that with React.)  Perhaps that tool doesn't properly understand JSX, or isn't configured to handle JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

class Index extends React.Component {
  state = {
    clicks: 0
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <App
        clicks={this.state.clicks}
        onClick={() => this.setState((props) => ({ clicks: props.clicks + 1 }))}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-firefly-i30t5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: the value is not incrementing